# Splunk Metrics {"text":"No data","code":5} error

Tags: curl, metrics, splunk

I'm trying to send metrics to Splunk via HEC, here's my curl command:

```
curl -k https://www.website.com                    \
-H "Authorization: Splunk password"       \
-d '{"index":"index-name","time": 313423232.000,"event":"metric","source":"disk","sourcetype":"perflog",
"host":"host_1.splunk.com","value":85,"fields":{"region":"us-west-1","datacenter":"dc1","rack":"63",
"os":"Ubuntu16.10","arch":"x64","team":"LON","service":"6","service_version":"0",
"service_environment":"test","path":"/dev/sda1","fstype":"ext3","metric_name:cpu.idle": 13.34}}'
```

And in return i'm getting:
{"text":"No data","code":5}

This is weird because it was working earlier, all I added was "value":85.
Could the issue be the website i'm sending to?

Some suggestions were mismatched quotes, and the fact that HEC only supports a specific set of known fields, but i don't think that's the issue i'm having here because i tried running the same curl command with only index, source, time, host, sourcetype, and event and got the same error code.

Comment: What HEC endpoint are you using?  Have you tried `"value":"85"`?

Answer (score 1):

To send a metric to Splunk HEC, you need to include the metric value in a field called `_value`. You also had a few errors in the last parameter in your example.

The following request should be sufficient.

```
curl -k https://www.website.com                    \
-H "Authorization: Splunk password"       \
-d '{"index":"index-name","time": 313423232.000,"event":"metric","source":"disk","sourcetype":"perflog",
"host":"host_1.splunk.com","fields":{"region":"us-west-1","datacenter":"dc1","rack":"63",
"os":"Ubuntu16.10","arch":"x64","team":"LON","service":"6","service_version":"0",
"service_environment":"test","path":"/dev/sda1","fstype":"ext3","metric_name": "cpu.idle", "_value": 13.34}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to remove fields that Splunk didn't like before I got a code 0.

```
curl -k ${SPLUNK_ENDPOINT}/services/collector -H "Authorization: Splunk ${SPLUNK_HEC_TOKEN}" -d '{"event": "Sourcetype test please", "sourcetype": "testsystem", "host": "some-host-123", "fields": {"tracking_id": 1234}}' ; echo
```

Which will return:

```
{"text":"Success","code":0}
```